# ElasticSearch: mapping to convert json String into json

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking into creating a mapping for a variety of data that's mostly simple, and have not done this before. One of the fields I need to map is a string representation of json that ideally would be json in elastic search.
The json string value sample:

```
"{\"United States\":{\"original\":\"United States\",\"importance\":\"1\"},\"Protestantism\":{\"original\":\"Protestantism\",\"importance\":\"1\"}}"
```

The size and values of the map representation are dynamic, so i understand that having it as a string makes sense, but I'm hoping there is a way to have it as json.

## 1 EDIT:

I just discovered there is a way to set up a pipeline processor designed to make this convertion: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/json-processor.html
I have not tried it yet, but this seems to be the closest thing so far to what i was looking for.

Comment: You would have to reindex this data in order to transform it. If you are passing this data through logstash you can use the `json { }` filter

Comment: @ugosan - no, I'm getting the data via aws SNS.

Comment: how are you inserting it in Elasticsearch, via the REST API? try not to "escape" the json before inserting it, so ES would recognize it as an object

Comment: @ugosan: I get data from InputStream, convert it to a String and use it as StringEntity in HttpPut. The data is a String from very start, before it is InputStream.

Comment: I do have same request as yours. Is there any solution on it?